# Getting hidden value in modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

**In Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
      $("#employeeInfo").on('click',function() {
             employee_info = $(this).closest("tr");
             emp_id = employee_info.find("#emp_id");
             modal_emp_id = $("#modal_emp_id");
             modal_emp_id.val(emp_id.val());
         });
    });
```

**In HTML**

```
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editEmployeeInfo' id='employeeInfo'>
        <input type="hidden" id="emp_id" name="emp_id" value="<?php $row["emp_id"] ?>"></input>
        <?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $row["department"]; ?></td>
    </tr>

     <div id='editEmployeeInfo' class='modal fade' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true' tabindex='-1'>
       <div class='modal-dialog'>
         <div class='modal-content'>
           <div class='modal-header'>
             <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
               <h4 class='modal-title'>Edit Employee Info</h4>
           </div>
               <div class='modal-body'>
               <input type="hidden" id="modal_emp_id" name="modal_emp_id"></input>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

When employee name is clicked, modal pops up.

I would like to get the emp_id of selected employee using Jquery.

The above is what I have tried.

Do you happen to know how to get the hidden value in jquery?

Comment: Are you using the same ID `employeeInfo` repeatedly? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. I am using the same id. When I click employee name, its id is also in modal to edit. IDs are unique

Comment: Use classes if you need to repeat them, not IDs. `class="employeeInfo"` and `class="emp_id"`

Comment: @Barmar oh I meant employee id. not IDs in HTML.

Comment: but it looks like you have a table, and each row has `<td data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editEmployeeInfo' id='employeeInfo'>`. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Barmar I misunderstood. let me try that. thank you

Comment: @Barmar In this case, how can I get the employee id in jquery from modal? The question you linked doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There's only one modal, so you can use IDs there. The problem is with the elements that are in the table rows.

Comment: @Barmar  What I am trying to do is kind of inserting the selected employee's id into the modal in order to edit its informaion. I think my jQuery is on the right track but have no ideas what's wrong even though I change IDs to class

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. You need to change the table rows to use classes instead of IDs, because you can't use the same `id=employeeInfo` and `id=emp_id` in every row.

Comment: Did you change the selectors to use `.` instead of `#` when you changed to classes?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I changed to ```#```. I understand that ids should be unique so changed to class. After that, I don't get how to achieve what I want. I tried the question you linked and remained what I had. Those are not working. Do you happen to know what I can try in Jquery?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do on model popup page because I have checked your code and you have already get the selected emp id into the hidden field in model pop up so is there any other thins i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the IDs in the table rows to classes, and change the selectors to use `.` instead of `#`.

In the snippet below I've changed the hidden input in the modal to a text input so you can see that it gets updated when you click on a name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".employeeInfo").on('click', function() {
    employee_info = $(this).closest("tr");
    emp_id = employee_info.find(".emp_id");
    modal_emp_id = $("#modal_emp_id");
    modal_emp_id.val(emp_id.val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editEmployeeInfo' class='employeeInfo'>
      <input type="hidden" class="emp_id" name="emp_id" value="123456"></input>
      John Smith
    </td>
    <td>
      Engineering
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id='editEmployeeInfo' class='modal fade' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true' tabindex='-1'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
        <h4 class='modal-title'>Edit Employee Info</h4>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <input type="text" id="modal_emp_id" name="modal_emp_id"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```